# trouble with testing advisory_lock with pytest

Tags: python, django, postgresql, multithreading, pytest

Im currently trying to test a function that will lock some string and will not allow to do anything under that locked string, using `advisory_lock`.

so here is my code:

```
import pytest

from django_pglocks import advisory_lock
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

def function_that_should_lock():
    with advisory_lock('secret_string', wait=True):
        sleep(10)


@eager_db_test
def test_lock():
    failed = False

    function_that_should_lock_thread = Thread(
        target=function_that_should_lock,
    )

    function_that_should_lock_thread.start()

    with advisory_lock('secret_string', wait=False):
        failed = True

    assert not failed
```

For some reason `function_that_should_lock` actually doesn't lock the string, and `failed` will be set to `True`.

Please help me understand how it works =)

Comment: Are you sure a PG instance is available? Have you contrasted behavior with / without the database running? Also, perhaps you'd like to try it using separate processes rather than separate threads.

Comment: Yeah. my ph instance is 100% available. If i turn it off ill get this error ```(<class 'RuntimeError'>, RuntimeError('Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.'), <traceback object at 0x137d11900>)````

Comment: Hmm, you might poke around with self.assertNumLocks a bit: https://github.com/Xof/django-pglocks/blob/master/django_pglocks/tests.py#L18-L32